# Smoothness of quotient map

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I'm a beginner in differential topology and was studying: *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* by John M. Lee. And came across an example (Example 2.13 e ) :

---

[image]

**Could someone please explain how one could deduce that the quotient map, used to define the projective space, is smooth based on the above example.**

Additionally here is the Example 1.33:

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, the maps are smooth simply by definition: map $f\colon (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto (f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n), \ldots, f_m(x_1, \ldots,x_n))$ is called smooth if for all possible $j, k$ there exists derivative $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_k}$, which is a continuous function in $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$. In the first example, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(\frac{x_j}{x_i})=\frac{1}{x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\frac{x_j}{x_i})=-\frac{x_j}{x_i^2}$ which are both continuous functions. Similarly for example $1.33$.

**Edit.** The definition given above is actually the definition of a $C^1$-smooth map. But I did not take into account that the word 'smooth' commonly means '$C^{\infty}$-smooth', i. e. there exist all possible higher partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^N f}{\partial x_{j_1}\partial x_{j_2} \ldots \partial x_{j_N}}$ (which are also automatically continuous). It is easy to see that in your example this condition holds: by differentiation of $\frac{x_j}{x_i}$ one can obtain only rational functions with some power of $x_i$ in the denominator. Such functions are defined and differentiable if $x_i \ne 0$.

Comment: You should also give an argument for the higher partial derivatives.

Comment: Oh, ok. I see it now. I was trying to find some deeper meaning . Great answer, really appreciated! Thanks @Ivan Beldiev!